# REST API design: do, then undo

Tags: rest, api

I am trying to write an api point that changes the status to "suspended" which looks straight forward

`PUT /api/artefacts/:id/status {"status": "SUSPENDED"}`

But now, unsuspending, isn't straight forward, it should check if the artifact is used elsewhere and return the new status, which might be `"UNUSED" or "USED"`, there is no "ACTIVE" or "UNSUSPENDED"

**So what would be the proper way to do it?**

`POST /api/artefacts/:id/unsuspend`

or 
`PUT /api/artefacts/:id/status {"status": "UNSUSPEND"}` which takes an non existing status, and lets the system act a bit differently than a straight forward patch?

---

**Edit** Changed PATCH to PUT

I wasn't quite happy with the solution, after more digging, and in compromising excellence, I came down to this:

`POST /api/artefacts/:id/status {"action": "Suspend"}`
`POST /api/artefacts/:id/status {"action": "Unsuspend"}`

- there is no verb, thus it makes sense that I am posting to the status
- the indirect status is hidden away in the body
- status now can accept any action, not just suspend and unsuspend, it could be "publish", "hide", "undo", etc.

Please share your input on the updated suggestion

Comment: At its heart HTTP is a remote document managment system and not a business rule system. All of the operations HTTP offer exist to interact with documents on a remote machine. Any business rule you determine are just side effects of the document management. REST, while not a protocol, requires that you adhere to the rules of the underlying transport protocol (HTTP in your case) to avoid interoperability issues. By that, you should follow the semantics of `PUT` and any other HTTP operations closely. PUT replaces the current representation with the provided payload and not just a single field

Comment: In addition to that, REST does not dictate how URIs are made up. There are certain people that do not want verbs in URIs and define such things as anti-pattern, but the truth is, REST really dosn't care much. REST, which is just a generatlization of the Web we are so used to, enforces the idea to link between content and data and use URIs to advance the current state to a new one. Instead of letting a client parse URIs, which might change over time, meaningful link relation names should be used that hint clients when to invoke these URIs instead.

Answer (score 2):

`PATCH` is meant to merely change an attribute on a resource without having to provide all attributes as you would using `PUT`.

It seems to me that there are two *actions* you can do to your resource, **suspend** and **unsuspend**. Especially the latter is a real action that needs to check something about the resource elsewhere in the system and return a state based on that check. In that case, I don't think `PATCH` is the method I would use.

I would probably model both actions on the resource like

```
POST /api/artefacts/:id/suspend
```

and

```
POST /api/artefacts/:id/unsuspend
```

This indicates more clearly to the client that these are non-idempotent actions on the resource and not just mere attribute changes.

Comment: but according to REST best practices, you really should not use verbs in the url, when you change a status, you PUT /status with a new value (or may be PATCH /artefact with new status?)

Comment: Which is true when status is a normal attribute of the resource. But in your case, it's not. You cannot set the status to unsuspended. So, suspend and unsuspend are actions on the resource, which you model via the non-idempotent POST method.

Comment: @Ayyash who defines such best practices? A client should *never* need to parse URIs, therefore it is irrelevant how these URIs are made up. What is far more important though is that meaningful link relation names like `next`, `prev`, `first` or `last` are used on i.e. collections. A client that is familiar with a certain representation format (i.e. application/vnd-collection+json) might see a URI with link relation name `next` and invoke the URI to retrieve the next page of the collection. This is where Fielding claims most of the design work needs to be, not tidy URIs